# Force EXIM to delay before forwarding

Tags: exim, mail-forwarding

I am setting up a phony user in EXIM to forward newsletters to a list of recipients. For some internal reason, I want it to wait 10 seconds before sending each mail(sending too rapidly triggers spam filters). Can I add delays into a .forward file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whose spam filters are you triggering?  Some sites will greylist on initial contact, but a 10 second delay will not likely help.  Normal queue and retry will work with this setup.

You might be able to do this with a second EXIM configuration and rate limiting calls between the servers.

The queue options might also help, but would impact other users.  A combination of queue_only_domains, and a low queue_run_max might help.

If your client is compliant, then a condition delay for the client in the configuration might also help.